# Mongo vs cassandra: single point of failure

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql, scalability, distributed-system

In Cassandra vs Mongo debate, it is said that as mongo has master-slave architecture so it has a single point of failure(master) as when master fails, slave nodes take time to decide for new master, hence a window for downtime.

With Cassandra we don't have this problem as all nodes are equal.
But then Cassandra too has a system wherein nodes use gossip protocol to keep themselves updated. In gossip protocol a minimum number of nodes are needed to take part. Suppose if one of the participating node goes down, then a new node needs to replace it. But it would take time to spawn a new replacement node, and this is a situation similar to master failure in mongo.

So what's the difference between 2 as far as single point of failure is concerned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions about Cassandra are not correct so allow me to explain.

Gossip does not require multiple nodes for it to work. It is possible to have a single-node cluster and gossip will still work so this statement is incorrect:

> In gossip protocol a minimum number of nodes are needed to take part.

For best practice, we recommend 3 replicas in each data centre (replication factor of 3) so you need a minimum of 3 nodes in each data centre. With a replication factor of 3, your application can survive a node outage for consistency levels of `ONE`, `LOCAL_ONE` or the recommended `LOCAL_QUORUM` so these statements are incorrect too:

> Suppose if one of the participating node goes down, then a new node needs to replace it. But it would take time to spawn a new replacement node, and this is a situation similar to master failure in mongo.

The only ways to introduce single points-of-failure to your Cassandra cluster are:

- deploying multiple instances on a single physical host (not recommended)
- using shared storage (e.g. SAN, NAS, NFS) for all nodes (not recommended)

As a side note, a friendly warning that other users may vote to close your question because comparisons are usually frowned upon since the answers are often [based on opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Cheers!

Comment: So when a read request arrvies at a node, then how does system decide which version (as there may be multiple versions of same data on diff replica nodes) to send back?

Comment: After the coordinator compares the results from the replicas that responded, only the newest version of the data (latest timestamp) is returned in the results. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Also your assumptions about MongoDB are not correct.

Master-Slave replication has been removed in MongoDB version 4.0 (current version is 5.0), nowadays it uses [Replica Sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#replication)

Typically you connect to a Replica Set rather than a single Replica Set member. When the current PRIMARY goes down, then a new PRIMARY will [elected](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) and your application will re-connect automatically and retries write operations to the new PRIMARY. It may hang for a few seconds but it should continue running.

Comment: so where does it put mongo in CAP universe...CP, AP, or it offers all?

Comment: To certain extent you can control by yourself, see [Causal Consistency and Read and Write Concerns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/causal-consistency-read-write-concerns/)